# WordPress child theme style.php edition

Tags: css, wordpress, caching, themes

A client have bought a wordpress theme,
And I am developing a child-theme.

I have duplicated the theme folder, renaming the second one -child, trying to follow the best practices.

Till now, I didn't have any problem editing files.
But there is a CSS rule in the style.php that I have to remove and cannot overwrite (left: 0 !important;)
So I would like to remove it from the style.php file of my theme.

In my local environment, it is working perfectly ;
But in production, the file in the browser is never updated, this CSS rule persists... However the file is physically correct, when I edit it with vim in SSH...
When I remove the file, the browser send me a logic 404...

I cannot figure if it comes from any caching (I don't have any caching plugin) ;
Or if it is related to the parent theme...
I have clean the browser caches several times, even tried to open a private navigation window, nothing is working...

Any trick about it ?

Comment: Is the second stylesheet in your child theme being served after the parent stylesheet? Are you also matching specificity with !important in your child theme?

Comment: My child style.php in loaded after my child style.css that includes the parent child.css.

In fact, I do not include the parent style.php, I just include the duplicated child one and try to edit it...

Comment: How is this file being loaded?

Comment: I am not really sure of what you are asking for, but it is included in any HTML head of page, within a <link rel='stylesheet' href='/.../style.php' /> tag.